# Database connecting but not inserting records?

Tags: php, mysql

Im putting together a simple script that pulls content from the tweetmeme api and then inserts it into a database for further formating. This is what i currently have but it inserts no records and returns no errors for the database connection so i can assume it connects and fails at the insertion.

```
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '****';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'footy';
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Couldnt connect to database table');



  $tweetmeme = "http://api.tweetmeme.com/stories/popular.xml?category=sports-soccer&count=30" ; 

  $xml = @simplexml_load_file($tweetmeme) or die ("no file loaded") ; 

 echo count($xml->stories->story)."stories in the XML file<br /><br />";
echo $xml->getName() . "<br /><br />";
foreach($xml->stories->story as $story)
{
    $title=$story->title;
    $url=$story->url;
    $media_type=$story->media_type;
    $created=$story->created_at;
    //$current_time=$date();
    $url_count=$story->url_count;
    $comment_count=$story->comment_count;
    $excerpt=$story->excerpt;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ft_tweets (title,url,media_type,created_at,mention_count,comment_count,excerpt) VALUES ($title,$url,$media_type,$created,$url_count,$comment_count,$excerpt)";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

doing a vardump() on the various items returns "object(SimpleXMLElement)" and this is what the xml structure looks like for an example [link text](http://api.tweetmeme.com/stories/popular.xml?category=sports-soccer&count=30)

Comment: Put a print statement inside your foreach loop and see if it is getting there first, and I would suggest you also print out the insert query and see if that works.

Comment: using echo $sql; after declaring $sql as above returns this:INSERT INTO ft_tweets (title,url,media_type,created_at,mention_count,comment_count,excerpt) VALUES (MARTIN SAMUEL: No one likes Ashley Cole, but you have to admit: He's good | Mail Online,http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-1309568/MARTIN-SAMUEL-No-likes-Ashley-Cole-admit-Hes-good.html,news,2010-09-06 23:14:35,12,0,Mail Online: MARTIN SAMUEL: No one likes Ashley Cole, but you have to admit: He's good: Despite the lurid headline... http://bit.ly/baG67n) which looks about right.

Comment: You're inerting raw strings into the query. You need to surround them with 'quotes' and run the text through `mysql_real_escape_string()` to generate a valid query. If you'd done any error checking with your `mysql_query()` call (`$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());` you'd have seen this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your query goes successful, try adding `or mysql_error()` like this to see if there is any error coming up:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: mysql_error reports "
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

Comment: sorry enter sends the post.. The error message finishes off with the first item being inserted so it fails immedietely

Comment: heres the table structure from the database if that helps: `ft_tweets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` text character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` text character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `media_type` set('news','video','image') character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` date NOT NULL,
  `added_at` date NOT NULL,
  `mention_count` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `comment_count` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `excerpt` text character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)